# Stolen MacBook Pro, name changed

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, password, find-my-iphone

My  MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) - 2.5GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
was stolen two days ago. I have notified the police.

I have clicked on “Notify me when found” on the Find my iPhone app on my iPhone. I have been checking Find My iPhone regularly over the last few days and it has always been 'offline' but a short while ago the name of my MacBook Pro has changed and the “Notify me when found” button has disappeared from the app. So I guess the thief has managed to change the name of the computer. I have selected the 'Erase Mac' option in Find My iPhone and this is now 'pending'.

The MacBook Pro was password protected. Fortunately, I have a Time Machine backup of the whole system.

My questions:

- Knowing now that someone is messing with it, should I click on “Lock”
   or “Erase Mac” or should I still wait and expect the thief to
  connect to be online to locate him?
- If the thief has been able to change the name of the computer what does that mean? Does this mean he must also have access to my files?
- Can he mess with my Apple ID? Will he be able to get any of my other passwords (social networks etc?).
- Now that I know the machine is still registering with Find My iPhone (under my account) can I assume the thief will not be able to get online without 'Erase my Mac' taking effect (and rendering the machine useless to him/her, or only until he can change the hard drive?).

Comment: If your MacBook is password protected, he shouldn't be able to access passwords, but if your machine's hard drive was not encrypted, he can access most of your files.

Comment: Any other idea how Apple's find my iPhone app can tell me that the name of MBP has changed without being able to tell its GPS position ? To my knowledge and reading this on several forums, Apple can only locate the user if he is online and only via Wi-Fi (not even via Ethernet cable) ! How on earth did they send the name change update !! I'm lost :(

Comment: My guess would be either the thief made it into your iCloud account and was able to change the name, or that they turned the Macbook on just enough to change the name but not long enough to erase it. Or they unlinked it from iCloud or something like that. It's really hard to tell and you don't have many options. Did you ever save your iCloud password in a browser like Chrome or Safari? Because then they might have gotten in and removed the Mac from iCloud. That's assuming they got into your Mac—did you have a password set? was it secure? what was the password hint? did you ever write it down?

Comment: Thanks @John Ramos, To my knowledge, I never saved my iCloud password on any browser and yes I had a password set for my Mac (over 12 numerics), don't really remember the hint though and I never wrote it down. Regarding the name change I've seen on some forums that the thief can access my computer as a guest and from there access the Mac's root settings and make changes !! what I still don't understand is how the app "find my iPhone" was able to detect that change without the thief connecting to Wi-Fi ?

Comment: I don't really understand that part either. Certainly you should set the machine to lock when it comes online, and setting up 2 factor authentication for your iCloud account is probably a good idea. Then an iPhone or iPad belonging to you or someone you trust is the only Two-Factor Authentication key, not SMS (which can easily be hacked and might send messages to Mac). Also, I don't believe he could turn off Find My Mac without your iCloud password. Nothing really you can do except secure things. (Good time to download a password manager and change all your passwords, I would say!)

Comment: Also, don't change your iCloud password, because that might affect your Mac's ability to reconnect to iCloud. But I don't think Two-Factor Authentication will stop the computer from connecting, it'll just stop a hacker, so I think you should set up 2-factor.